# How do I filter a DataList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ID="orderdatalist">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <td>
                    Order Number:
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label DataField="oID" Text='<%# Eval("oID") %>' ID="orderidlabel"></asp:Label>
                </td>                
                <td>
                    USER ID:
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" DatField="oUser_ID" Text='<%# Eval("oUser_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    ORDER STATUS:
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" DataField="oDelivery_Status" Text='<%# Eval("oDelivery_Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>                 
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Above is the code for my asp page. I have a dropdown list with the following options: "**Cancelled**","**Delivered**" and "**Order Placed**". What I am trying to do here is **to filter the datalist according to the dropdownlist value**. E.g. If I click "Cancelled", the datalist will only show records which has "Cancelled" under the oDelivery_Mode field. Tried searching online but most are solutions to gridview etc. and none are about datalists. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This issue in not specific to GridView or DataList. All you need to do is set certain properties of SqlDataSource.

You can user FilterParameters and FilterExpression properties of SqlDataSource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnctionString="<<connectionstring>>" SelectCommand="<<selectcommand>>" FilterExpression="oDelivery_Status = {0}">
  <FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="OrderStatus" ControlID="<<dropdownlistid>>" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
  </FilterParameters>
 <asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am not sure of the connectionstring, select command and Id of the dropdownlist. So I have put the placeholders for them you need to use proper values there.

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FilterParameters`. Change the values according to your need.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ID="orderdatalist">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <td><%# Eval("OrderID") %>
                        </td>
                        <td><%# Eval("OrderName") %> 
                        </td>
                        <td><%# Eval("OrderStatus") %> 
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource
                ID="SqlDataSource1"
                EnableCaching="true"
                DataSourceMode="DataSet"
                runat="server"
                SelectCommand="select * from [Order]"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
                FilterExpression="OrderStatus = '{0}'">
                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter
                        Name="orderparam"
                        ControlID="ddlOrderStatus"
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrderStatus" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOrderStatus_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Cancelled" Value="Cancelled"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Delivered" Value="Delivered"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="OrderPlaced" Value="OrderPlaced"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

protected void ddlOrderStatus_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   orderdatalist.DataBind();
}
```